# What type will let Control codes pass through the Blob() API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, download, blob

I just discovered today about the Blob() API, trying to download text into a file, from some `input` and `span` elements on my site.  The problem is that the Blob(), no matter what type I give it, removes all the control codes, at least the essential ones like \n\r.

This is the code I am using to download data constructed as an ASCII file:

```
    function saveTextAsFile2(){
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.URL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
```

I tried these types to no avail...

```
{type:'octet/stream'}
{type:'file'}
```

When the function is called the text is displayed in a textArea element as follows:

[image]

When downloaded, however, in the file it looks like this:

- Line 1   - Fine line 2   - Line 3

If anyone could explain how this should be set up for the control codes to pass through the download, I would appreciate it greatly.

Regards,

DK

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer, while testing things.  It turns out that MS NotePad ignored the control codes as they come through the Blob().  All other editors recognize the control codes!  Wackey stuff from MS!  To avoid that problem, since I default to NotePad with the "*.txt" files, I will have to download with a different extension and fire it up with one of the other editors.

Thank you all who attempted to help by reading the question.

The good old Reagan slogan, Trust, but verify MS products still holds!

DK